# Hive: How to insert data in a column of type array <string>

Tags: arrays, hive

Have a table with following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE `student_details`(
  `id_key` string, 
  `name` string, 
  `subjects` array<string>)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  'path'
```

When trying to insert the values in the table getting an error message:

Tried:

```
INSERT INTO student_details  values ('AA87U','BRYAN',array('ENG','CAL_1','CAL_2','HST','MUS'));
```

Error:

```
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10293]: Unable to create temp file for insert values Expression of type TOK_FUNCTION not supported in insert/values
```

This doesn't make sense to me. Tried looking online and found a similar one: [ExternalLink](https://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/Unable-to-create-temp-file-for-insert-values-Expression-of-type-TOK-FUNCTION-not-supported-in-insert-values-error-with-Apache-Hive-ODBC-driver). The solution also not making any sense.

Any help please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't insert a complex type directly in Hive.

Either you have to create a dummy table like below:

```sql
INSERT INTO student_details select 'AA87U','BRYAN', array('ENG','CAL_1','CAL_2','HST','MUS') from dummy;
```

For Hive 2+, you can run without dummy table.

```sql
INSERT INTO student_details select 'AA87U','BRYAN', array('ENG','CAL_1','CAL_2','HST','MUS');
```

Comment: insert into blablabla select array('a', 'b') doesn't work, when blablabla contains a single column of type array<string>.

Answer (score 0):

You have to first create a dummy table **with one row**:

```
create table dummy(a int);
insert into dummy values (1);
```

then you can do this:

```
INSERT INTO student_details select 'AA87U','BRYAN', array('ENG','CAL_1','CAL_2','HST','MUS') from dummy;
```